# Two instances of constructor, different number of parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a problem with my derived class called `Square`. A square's sides are always equal, so I want there a way for me to send it to the parent class (`Rectangle`) in a way that it doesn't call the default constructor, but provides a constructor with 1 parameter. However, it finds a problem that it can't tell the difference between the default constructor and the constructor for when the length and width are the same. Is there any way I can explicitly make sure that the Square constructor doesn't call the default constructor instead of the preferred?

````cpp
class Rectangle : public Quadrilateral
{
private:
    int length{};
    int width{};

public:
    Rectangle(int len = 1, int wid = 1) : length{ len }, width{ wid }
    {
    }

    Rectangle(int s) : length{ s }, width{ s }
    {
    }

    const int area() { return length * width; }
};

class Square : public Rectangle
{
private:
    int side{};

public:
    Square(int s = 1) : Rectangle{ s }  // Call Rectangle w/ one parameter
    {
    }

    int getSide() const { return side; }

    int perimeter() { return 4 * side; }
};```
````

Comment: It's worth noting that some consider Inheriting `Square` from `Rectangle` a violation of [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Remove default parameters from `Rectangle(int len = 1, int wid = 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are two ways to get a `Rectangle` when you have an `int`. One is to call the first constructor with `wid` as the default `1`, and the other is to call the single argument constructor.

I would argue that this is the result of using default values for parameters. If you need default values, I'd say just make another overload of the function that accepts one fewer parameter and forwards the call to the other function, passing the default value. This way you'll quickly notice that you have two overloads with the exact same signature (taking one `int`).

You either:

- Make up your mind and decide what `Rectangle(int)` means (either it's just `length` with default `width`, or it's both `length` and `width`)
- Call the `Rectangle` constructor with two arguments in the first place in `Square(int)`